# Robotium: Shall I always run my tests with screen turned on?

Tags: android, robotium, instrumentation

Didn't find it in documentation, but shall I always run my tests on device which is turned on? If I run them with a screen turned off I got different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want the screen unlocked, having the lock screen on will cause you to have lots of failures.

The simplest way to do this is to turn off screen locking in settings (available on ics+) but if you cannot do that you can either disable it in code (requires an android permission) or install third party apps to let you do such a thing.